# Custom command in server minecraft

Tags: minecraft

Forge 1.16.5 in a single world the command works but not on the server. I need to fix this

```
private static LiteralArgumentBuilder<CommandSource> cLiteral(String test) {
        return LiteralArgumentBuilder.literal(test);
    }
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onRegisterCommandEvent(RegisterCommandsEvent event){
        cRegister(event.getDispatcher());
    }

    private static void cRegister(CommandDispatcher<CommandSource> dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.register(
                cLiteral("test")
                        .executes(context -> {
                            ((ClientPlayerEntity) Minecraft.getInstance().player).chat("123");
                            return 1;
                        })

        );
    }
```

I need the command to be available at all times

Comment: I really need your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to create a command in the mod so that it is displayed and works on servers in Minecraft.
As an example /s -> /spawn